# Using Regex to search for several occurrences of a word

Tags: regex, linux, grep

How do I search for x or more occurrences of a word using regular expressions and grep in a .txt file in a linux terminal, for example, find all lines with 4 or more "and"s in Sample.txt.

Comment: Does the `and` in `hand` or `android` count?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
egrep "and(.*?and){3}" data.txt
```

And to match `"and"` regardless of case (`"And"` or `"AND"`, ...), but skip an `"and"` that is a part of another word (or name), try:

```
egrep -i "\band\b(.*?\band\b){3}" data.txt
```

The `-i` makes it ignore case, and the word boundaries, `\b`, will disregard occurrences like `"Anand"` and `"Anderson"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match `and` but not `bandit`, use something like the following:

```
egrep '\band\b(.+?\band\b){3}' Sample.txt
```